# parse json with forward slash

Tags: java, android, json

How should I parse this json?

```
{"label":"KLM/AirFrance"}
```

I try

```
jsonObject.getString("label")
```

But have got an error:

```
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Code:

```
ArrayList<Gate> gates = new ArrayList<Gate>();
JSONArray jGates = object.getJSONArray("gates_info");
int gatesLength = jGates.length();
for (int i=0; i<gatesLength; i++) {
    Gate gate = new Gate();
    JSONObject jGate = jGates.getJSONObject(i);
    gate.setId(jGate.getInt("id"));
    gate.setLabel(jGate.getString("label"));
    gate.setCurrency_code(jGate.getString("currency_code"));
    gates.add(gate);
}
```

Part of response:

```
"gates_info":[{"id":48,"label":"KLM/AirFrance","payment_methods":
["card"],"currency_code":"usd","is_airline":true},
{"id":1,"label":"Nabortu","payment_methods":
["bank","yandex_money","web_money","terminal","card","svyaznoy","euroset"],
"currency_code":"rub","is_airline":false},    
{"id":3,"label":"anywayanyday.com","payment_methods": 
["card","euroset","svyaznoy"],"currency_code":"rub","is_airline":false},
{"id":7,"label":"Ozon.travel","payment_methods":
["cash","yandex_money","web_money","terminal","card","elexnet","contact","euroset"],
"currency_code":"rub","is_airline":false}, 
{"id":8,"label":"tickets.ru","payment_methods":
["card","web_money"],"currency_code":"rub","is_airline":false}
```

Comment: which json library are you using? Looks like the one from android SDK but better be sure before answering

Comment: Is that the exact format you are trying to parse? How are you initializing the `jsonObject`?

Comment: @jolivier yes, you are right. This is android.

Comment: Either the parser's broken or you're not using it right.  There's nothing special about `/` in JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks all works except this case

Comment: Please show more code and the full stacktrace of the error. There's nothing special about the forward slash. Your problem most likely has nothing to do with the slash.

Comment: @Codo there is a lot of code. The response is very large. My code is full working except this case. When I have usual string without "/" all works fine.

Comment: Either the error does not occur on the line you have posted, or you call `getString` on the wrong object, i.e. a JSON object that doesn't correspond to the JSON data you have pasted. Either way, the question contains insufficient information to diagnose the real problem.

Comment: @Codo I've just added a part of my code and a part of response (as answer because of formatting)

Comment: @Metalex: Thanks for posting the additional information. Yet your code looks ok and the JSON data (when put in the right context) is okay as well. Are you sure the exception occurs on `getString("label")`? And are you sure it happens on the JSON object containing "KLM/AirFrance"? It's simply not consistent with the error message.

Comment: So where, precisely, is the error being raised?

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape forward slash, i.e. write `\\/`.
The back slash is written twice to escape itself, i.e. to make interpreter to treat it as a "real" back slash.

I have not tried this myself with JSON but typically such problems are solved using this kind of solutions.

Comment: There is nothing special about a forward slash. There's no need to escape it. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: -1: Looking at your answer again: why should a back slash have a special effect? In JSON, it's an ordinary character (unlike C, C# or Java). Your answer does not help and - even worse - just adds a lot of confusion.

Comment: you taged your question as java, the backslash is not important at all, I wa explaining how to covert your data to JSON formatt. Sorry if you are not able to understand! good luck with JSON I think you have a ways to go....

Answer (score 0):

Here I had this problem (it nothing to do with escape characters though. You just need to know how to use Json. You need to use the addProperty function: Here is an example you should be able to copy this and get it.

```
JsonObject temp = new JsonObject();
temp.addProperty(tagName,stringData);
```

Comment: The class `JsonObject` has no `addProperty` method. So I don't see how this would help.

Comment: try it this works, I have used it several time myself (you have to dig deeper into the API to find it , it is inhertated from its parent class.

Comment: This question is about the Android [org.json.JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class. It has no `addProperty` method and is a direct subclass of `Object`, which doesn't have such a method either. I think you're talking about a different JSON class library.